# König der Löwen - Deklination von Nomen

Tags: nominative, declension

`der Löwe` hat im Nominativ Singular keine Endung, sonst immer die Endung -n oder -en.

I don‘t understand why the singular nominative form of `der Löwe` has **-n** ending in `König der Löwen`. I would understand if it was actually `die Löwen` and it is in `Genitiv` form ==> der `Löwen`.

Can anyone please explain me why it is `König der Löwen` and not `König der Löwe`? Thanks :)

Comment: It actually _is_ genitive plural, "king of the lions" or "König der Löwen".

Comment: But it is known in English as „The Lion King“, is it translated differently in German?

Comment: If I remember the story correctly, you could probably call Mustafa (and later Simba) both, "the lion's king" or "king of the lions" as well as "the lion king" (the king of all animals, who happens to be a lion). So both variants are fitting. "Der König der Löwen" probably has a better ring to it, and there's a different animated series called [Simba, der Löwenkönig](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simba,_der_L%C3%B6wenk%C3%B6nig). Maybe the creators of the German version of the Disney movies wouldn't take chances colliding with that. But that's mostly speculation.

Comment: For future reference, the German titles of books, movies, etc. are often wildly different from their English counterparts. For example the German title of "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly" is "Zwei glorreiche Halunken". The change from "The Lion King" to "König der Löwen" is relatively minor in comparison.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck, I think you meant "the lions' king" (not lion's).

Comment: @CarstenS You're correct, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You analyzed it correctly. The part "der Löwen" is in genitive case. It is a genitive attribute of the noun "König". A genitive attribute contains the information to whom the referred noun belongs. Here it says, that the King belongs to the lions.

The English translation is

> Der König der Löwen
> The king of the lions

The original english title of this movie is *"the lion king".* The German translation is:

> The lion king
> Der Löwenkönig

But this exact translation sounds boring in German. The other version sound a little bit more exciting.

---

The version you suggested doesn't make any sense:

> Der König der Löwe
> The king the lion

It is just a list of two nouns that are not connected to each other.

Comment: I think  _Der König der Löwe_ was a miscarried attempt to form the Genitive Singular. This would be _Der König des Löwen_.

Comment: "Der König, der Löwe" or "Der Löwe, der König" would be possible-ish translations that are near to what I guess was meant by the idea "König der Löwe" in the question. Both don't work as movie titles of course.